# bitmap image into Base64(blob), and try to save in mysql error in connection

Tags: android

I convert the bitmap image into Base64(blob), and try to save in mysql but "error in connection".
android-unable-to-insert-data-in-mysql-database

```
protected void saveBitmap() {

     String image_str;


         try{
                //save as byte
             ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream); //compress to which format yo want.
             byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
             image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);
                 ////test
             ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
             nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("img",image_str));
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Not converted to byte", 0).show();
         }

         try{
             String url ="http://10.0.2.2/android/image.php";           
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
             HttpResponse httpresponse=httpclient.execute(httppost);

         }   
         catch(Exception e)
         {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection failed", 0).show();
         }
}
```

Comment: In what line are you getting the error? Also I think you mean Base64 and not byte64

Comment: yes base64, their is a exception in http connection making

Comment: ok, please post the Logcat output when the exception is raised.

Comment: logcat http://i.imgur.com/kg9Cm33.png?1

Comment: Instead of capturing the exception and doing a toast, remove the toast, let the app crash and add the logcat to your question.

Answer (score 1):

change your compress type into your image format i use the JPEG in my code and also put same string in BasicNameValuePair[![enter image description here][1]][1] as you give column name into your database. for this you can see my below code

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,10, baos);
    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    String temp= Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);

    return temp;
}
```